# Checking if numbers are even or odd in lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I need to write a recursive method in lisp that doubles the odd values and leaves the even values alone.

So far i have:

```
(defun MY-DOUBLE-ODD (n)
   (if (oddp n)
     (setq n (* n 2)))
   n)
```

However, I just can't figure out how to have this recursive method go through an entire list.

How do I fix it to make it iterate through `(MY-DOUBLE-ODD (1 2 3 4 5 6))`
??

Comment: Use a separate function for the recursive processing, and have it call `MY-DOUBLE-ODD` on each element as it's going.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should not involve `setq` at all. The recursion should be used to iterate the list of arguments, using `car` to get the first element, `cdr` to get the rest of the list to recurse on, and `cons` to construct the result on return from the recursive call.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `setq` internally within the function that returns the possibly doubled number.

Comment: Well, it should return the double. `Setq` is often a code smell for such trivial tasks.

Comment: The `setq` usage obfuscates the intent of the code, which is to return evens unchanged and odds doubled. The code does do that, but again, makes that hard to see. The noob is learning Lisp for a reason, so encouraging a functional style makes sense.

Comment: Barmar, not gonna argue with *you* about lisp, but seriously would you use setq for this piece of code? I didn't mention it as style criticism, but to help steer someone working on a homework problem toward a clean solution. I mean half the trick here is trying to help someone who is asking a homework question. Perhaps I should just not do that as a matter of practice...

Comment: So what exactly is the answer here? I have the same question as OP and I'm failing to see any value w. this answer.